# Access to Angular Material Element's nativeElement

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have an Angular 13 site in which I use the methods of a material stepper. I also would like to work on the DOM element of the stepper. It seems I can either use it as a MatStepper and declare it like this:

```
  @ViewChild('stepper')
  stepper: MatStepper;
```

But then I can not get to this.stepper._elementRef.nativeElement.

Or use the stepper as an elementRef:

```
  @ViewChild('stepper', {read: ElementRef})
  stepper: MatStepper;
```

But then I can't use the methods and properties of a MatStepper element.

How can I have acces both the MatStepper and the ElementRef methods and properties?

Answer (score 0):

Do it twice, duh

```
  @ViewChild('stepper')
  stepper: MatStepper;

  @ViewChild('stepper', {read: ElementRef})
  stepperElement: ElementRef;
```